# Why is the text editor of Stack Overflow so bad?

Tags: feature-request, editor

I don't know if anyone is feeling the same as me, but the text editor of SO is just awful for editing code. For example:

- You cannot quickly indent a line with tab. If you press tab, the text editor loses focus and the focus moves somewhere else.
- You cannot decrease the indent level quickly (for example with shift + tab)

All of the above can be done with the text editor used by GitHub. Can SO please improve its text editor? At the moment, every time I need to copy/paste a piece of code into my SO question I had to copy it into my text editor (Sublime Text) to increase/decrease the indentation first then copy it back to the SO editor. It's very annoying.

Comment: Don't edit code in the editor. I know that seems counter-intuitive, but you should nearly always be pasting in working code. The same code that gave you the error. Otherwise you just create errata.

Comment: Also, indentation should generally be using spaces here, anyway. Much as I personally prefer tabs, spaces are what triggers code block detection. And, if you're using them, the little `{ }` button (or its keyboard equivalent, `CTRL+k`) on the menu bar will add the indentation needed to a whole block at once.

Comment: the problem is, for example, many times my code is multi-level indented, so to make it looks nice on SO I had to reduce the indentation, I can't just paste it in as-is. Not to mention not all the time I paste code in there, sometimes I type code in to answer a question as well

Comment: While it's not completely intuitive, you can use `ctrl-K` to indent and dedent code.

Comment: also by saying "pressing tab" I don't say that it will have to insert tabs. It can insert multiple spaces also. This is also configurable by the user with the github text editor.

Comment: @dmckee I can see how this benefits asking a question but most of the time I give code examples in my answers. To go back and forth between SO and an editor is not a great solution.

Comment: @hitautodestruct Er ... I generally *run* the code in my answers as well. I agree that you can often answer simple question without that step, but once you code is complicated enough to need a lot of formatting the chances of introducing an error go up. In any case, I am not among the downvoters here, I just don't prioritize this very high.

Comment: I'd also like to have a indent feature available as e.g. the [ideone code editor](http://ideone.com/) offers. And yes, I also tend to copy code there, and publish runnable code examples, but sometimes (e.g. when editing OP's posted code), it would be pretty neat to have such editor feature (and if simply selecting some text, and pick a _'code format'_ action, may be with a dialog, requiring additional information/property settings).

Comment: It's kinda sad that a site dedicated to code does not have a decent text editor for working with code.

Answer (score 17):

I just wrote a Chrome Extension that replaces the default text editor with a better one (SimpleMDE):

**[Better Stack Exchange - Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-stack-exchange/ohgloaohphplfbdcbkoobcmbjopjbhnl)**

It has full support for <kbd>SHIFT+Tab</kbd> quick indentation and all those other goodies you'd expect from a text editor.

---

P.S., I wrote this answer using the extension... Here's how it looks like (*meta meta stack overflow*)!

[image: alt]

---

Original SlackApps post: [Better Stack Exchange - awesome new text editor and UI improvements](https://stackapps.com/questions/6926/better-stack-exchange-awesome-new-text-editor-and-ui-improvements)

Comment: Pretty nice, but I'm only seeing it for questions?

Comment: Hey! :D Could you give me a URL that I can test it on? @Shog9

Comment: This page is as good as any - I'm getting "index.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" in the console. That said, I am running a beta channel version of Chrome, so could just be a bug in that.

Comment: Ahhh thanks for the catch, @Shog9. I know what the problem is :) I'll work on a fix :D

Comment: Hey @Shog9, I fixed the problem. Once you get the 0.0.3 update, it should work as advertised.. Thanks again! :)