# Double revert when pressing Ctrl+Z after pasting in an answer field. Pasting something is a forgotten step so that two steps get reverted

Tags: bug, editor

#### 230823 Cross-site duplicate

This is a cross-site duplicate of Stack Exchange Meta [`Ctrl+Z` undoes twice in editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor/392483#392483).

#### Embedding

The other question, *[Why is the undo operation in text boxes so coarse-grained?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355277/why-is-the-undo-operation-in-text-boxes-so-coarse-grained)*, is in its core about the entered text "in a row" (though it also mentions pasting, but it does not show its question clearly enough as a pasting bug). The header here is about pasting. This is not about how coarsely entered text gets reverted. The question here is about a clear bug, since anything pasted is *just not counted as a step at all*. This has nothing to do with coarse-grained actions since I can type something and revert only the typed last step when I jump between lines and words and type somewhere else before reverting. Not with pasted text or pictures.

##### "Revert" steps back twice over anything that is pasted

This is about the editor for an "answer" field. In a "comment" field, everything works.

You can test this anywhere. It is always the same. If you type a word and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, that word is removed and everything is fine.

If you type a word and add `[]` around that `word` like this: `[word]`, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> also just reverts *one* step.

But: if you paste a URL now, and you revert that step, you will also lose another step before the pasting step. The same with pictures.

##### Zooming into one use case: pasting a URL

If you add a link, and you first write `[]()`, which I always do, and then go to the page you want to link to, copy the header or the URL, and then **paste** the URL in the wrong `[]` for the header instead of the right `()` for the URL - and if you *then* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, you lose not only the link, but also the `[]()`.

It seems to be something linked to pasting. Pasting itself seems not to be seen the same as typing, since when I type, it reverts only the last "neighboured" typing. This can be many words that get reverted, but it is clear that this is not about spaces and it is about words that are typed in a row that would be cleared altogether.

If I type `[]()` and then **write** something between one of the brackets, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and revert *only* the typed word, while `[]()` would still be there.

Again: if I instead paste something between one of the brackets and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, it would not just clear what was pasted, but it would also clear the `[]()`.

This happened so often to me that I drop this here now. I often do not press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> anymore, but instead mark the whole URL that mistakenly is in the header place (or the header that mistakenly is in the URL place) and press <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> which costs more time and nerves. Could it not just do *one* revert as soon as you type signs like `[]()`? Or could *pasting* be made a typing step?

##### FCI (Full Config Info)

I have had this problem over the years in each Firefox browser version I have ever used. Now I have Firefox version 99.0 (64-bit).
`lsb_release -a` gives me

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

And the same on a FF on Windows 10.

Comment: No repro FF 98.0b5 (64-bit), Win 11 Pro (nor 98.0b8, nor 98.0b9... I had some updates to apply)

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I have this on any computer. Since the start of membership. Linux, Windows, various versions, always Firefox.

Comment: That's fine, I was just  saying that _I_ wasn't able to reproduce it.

Comment: I've reproduced this before (various versions of Firefox), but it's super inconsistent. Not sure what the deal is. seen similar behavior in other editors though (read: outside browsers), I assume it's how they implement history

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I can do it with the examples given in the text over and over again, it is always the same, it is not inconsistent. After typing, it reverts 1 step, after pasting, it reverts two steps. Pasting is as if nothing has happened.

Comment: Yep, most times I've pressed control-Z when in the editor, I've regretted it. I've learned to only delete things with highlight / backspace / delete. I wish the control-Z behavior was the same as in a standard textarea, which is much more predictable and consistent.

Comment: Undo behavior has always been broken (repro in Firefox 99.0a1, Linux). When adding new lines with content, then Undoing, each line is removed separately, but when Redoing, the linebreak and the contents of the line are re-inserted separately. When pasting something _n_ times, each Undo will remove _two_ copies, and each Redo will re-introduce _one_ copy **except the last**. This will need to be addressed in the [new Stacks editor](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/289905); the current editor will be replaced. Note that _comments_ are a normal `<textarea>` and work fine (@Nick, check again?).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Could you make this an answer, that this is done in the new editor? And if it was always broken and everybody had this problem, why has no one ever asked this here? This must be a cross-platform duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine I have no idea if this is fixed in the new editor, and I don’t really know if this was broken since the beginning, but it has been a problem for a very long time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the undo operation in text boxes so coarse-grained?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355277/why-is-the-undo-operation-in-text-boxes-so-coarse-grained)

Comment: @JohnMontgomery No, See the edit in the question.

Comment: @OP, what about mentioning your FCI...? (= "Full Config Info", = the "Basic Info" when reporting a "Bug"), => Browser + Version + OS...? (+ Have you tried in several FCI's/Browsers...?)

Comment: This is [an old and well known (general) problem with Firefox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285064/what-causes-you-to-abandon-an-edit/285074#285074). I always assumed it was a Firefox problem only (not related to Stack Overflow). Perhaps it isn't?

Comment: It *does* seem to behave differently on Stack Exchange (I tried it [on this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/706859/edit)) and on Wikipedia (I tried it [on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Central_processing_unit&action=edit)). Firefox 99.0 on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) (yes, I know, but there was failing hardware) with [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) configured for the minimum for Stack Exchange regular operations (but not *google.com* for the bot check).

Comment: Another way to reproduce it (without the need of repositioning the cursor): ***1) Type one word (without spaces) 2) Type a space 3) Paste 4) Type a space 5) Type one word (without spaces) 6) Ctrl + Z.*** Notes: 1) The two spaces are not necessary, but it makes it clearer what is going on (for separation). 2) The clipboard content for pasting does not need to be a URL.)

Comment: To be clear: I can reproduce this problem.

Comment: (The JavaScript requirements are in *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)* (it is incomplete, though. For instance, it doesn't cover the cookie dialogs.))

Comment: @PeterMortensen That is a good use case on top what I wrote since you show here that the pasting is even reverted when it is second last, not just the last action.

Comment: FF98 + Win10_Pro (with '*Win10 Clipboard Cloud Sync*' disabled): No Repro in a `Comment` Field, Behaviour looks "normal" to me, but Repro indeed in an/the `Answer` Field (on this current Page), both using @PeterMortensen's Steps and #OP's `[]()` + an URL pasted in the "wrong" `[]` part, => The whole Line "disappears"...!, oops...! :shocking:  // In all Cases, "*easy Workaround*" is `Ctrl^y` which brings "everything" back... :idea: (The `Ctrl^y` needs to be done directly after the "faulty" `Ctrl^z`, or I get some "strange and not consistent" Results...)

Comment: @chivracq Can you make this an answer? Pressing `Ctrl+y` right after the faulty `Ctrl+z` is as if the right `Ctrl+z` worked from the start, as you write it. It is then a good workaround until the faulty revert gets fixed, if it ever does.

Comment: Hum, OK (@OP), just back from a Festival and your Reply is hum... 1 year later, so I'll need to completely re-dig into the Thread and redo all my Testing before I could convert my previous Comment from 1 year ago to an Answer... // FF98 is now FF[111-113] (May 2023), I'm still on Win10_Pro (with a few Updates also of course, but I had not mentioned the exact Version, ah-ah...!). I'll have a look "tomorrow"...

Comment: @chivracq Well it is easy to test `Ctrl+Z` and `Ctrl+Y` in the main window, takes a minute. You should refresh from the festival before doing the buro work!

Comment: @chivracq taking the time for an answer now?

Comment: The explanation is in *[Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor/203190#203190)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Should we make this a duplicate of the other question? Ah I see it is cross-site. And the next question is, why, if it is such a plain bug, could this but stay for over a decade? I vaguely remember having had this bug also in another online editor that was not at all linked to Stack Exchange. Perhaps, this bug is built in?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I cross-site duplicated the answer to your Stack Exchange Meta link. Btw I often need to ask questions on Stack Overflow Meta since I have been banned for questions on Stack Exchange Meta about three times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Making [another one's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3799241/chivracq) an answer, here is at least a good workaround:*

If you run into a double reverting `Ctrl+Z`, just press `Ctrl+Y` once and it will be as if `Ctrl+Z` was done just once.

And whoever reads this and can fix this editor bug of over a decade, please do so.